# Audacity | Track Name (layers) | batch-export all of track-audio according to it's given Name

Tags: audio, batch, export, audacity

`Audacity 2.1.2
Windows7_x64_hp`

Using `Audacity` as my preferred *audio-editor*, I've managed to use it long enough to understand it's mistakes and hassles.

## PROBLEM

- I want to be able to Batch-export each `Track-Layer` (with the same *file-type*) all-while keeping it's name as-per Track-Layer.

## EXAMPLE

- 1st Track-Layer

  - *01_beat_JohnDoe_homemadebeat*
- 2nd Track-Layer

  - *02_verse1_SmithWesson*

At this point, I want to be able to export all of the listed track layer's (here, we have 2-layers) with the corresponding name of the track.

---

### NOTE

- Track-Layers listed must be exported as

  - *.wav-32bit*
  - *automatically keep it's own track-layer name*
  - *location of export is up to the user*

Answer (score 0):

## [SOLVED]

- Once your ready to export your track-layers (*with each being properly labeled*)

  - File > Export Multiple...

Once there, you have the option to export as a single format to follow all throughout for all track-layers.

### NOTE

- You can't select which multiple tracks to batch-export

  - it'll default to `all track-layers unmuted`
- You must have more than 1 track-layer as only having a single or a single while others are muted isn't acceptable in Audacity.